# How to get up to 3 first and last items from an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, pagination

I am working on pagination with react. I want to show the first 3 pages and then three dots when the user clicks on the dots they will become an input and users can type in a page number and finally the last 3 pages. something like this:

```
<< 1 2 3 ... 10 11 12 >>
```

but with my current code If I've an array of 4 pages. I get:

```
<< 1 2 3 ... 2 3 4 >>
```

How to handle this case ? any suggestions ?

```
const pagesArr = [...Array(data.pageCount).keys()].map((x) => ++x); // [1, 2, 3, ... 10, 11, 12]

<>
{pagesArr.slice(0, 3).map((p) => (
  <a
    key={p}
    href='#'
    className='z-10 bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600 relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border text-sm font-medium'
  >
    {p}
  </a>
))}
{pagesArr.length > 6 && (
  <span className='relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-700'>
    ...
  </span>
)}
{pagesArr.slice(Math.max(pagesArr.length - 3, 1)).map((p) => (
  <a
    key={p}
    href='#'
    className='z-10 bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600 relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border text-sm font-medium'
  >
    {p}
  </a>
))}
</>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would just check to see if pagesArr.length > 6, if not then map all 6?

Comment: I see. so you're saying if there are less than 6 pages. just iterate over the pages. but if there are more than 6 pages use the current code. right ?

Comment: Exactly! Because you also won’t need the ellipsis for 6 pages too